# how to insert some text in all django context using django middleware

Tags: python, django, templates

this my middleware code :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import RequestContext

class BeforeFilter(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        settings.my_var = 'Hello World'
        request.ss = 'ssssssssss'
        return None
    def process_response(self, request, response):

        return response
```

this is the settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'middleware.BeforeFilter',
)
```

and the view is :

```
#coding:utf-8

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.template import RequestContext


def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context['a'] = 'aaaa'
    return render_to_response('a.html',context)
```

the html is :

```
{{a}}fffff{{ss}}
```

but it not show {{ss}}:

```
aaaafffff
```

so how do i show :

```
aaaafffffssssssss
```

how to insert some text in all django context  using django middleware,

so that i cant use to insert the text everytime ,

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To meet your initial goal, I do not think the **BeforeFilter** middle ware is required. What we need is just a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors).

Write a context processor as following:

```
#file: context_processors.py

def sample_context_processor(request):
   return {'ss':'ssssssssss'} #or whatever you want to set to variable ss
```

then add the context processor to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS list

```
#file: settings.py 

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'myproject.context_processors.sample_context_processor',
)
```

Comment: OP asked how to do it using django middleware, not template context processor

Comment: This can be accessed in the template just like this {{ ss }}.
I also wanted to do some data injection with middleware. But the HttpResponse and TemplateResponse made me use both of them :|

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that you accessing `request` in the template. If you do just `{{ss}}` the variable does not exist since it an attribute of `request` (you did `request.ss = 'ssssssssss'`, right?). So do `{{request.ss}}` in your template and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked for how to do this with middleware but I found this question without needing that requirement. The currently accepted answer is outdated and the edit queue is full.

As of Django 1.10, the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting has been moved to the `context_processors` option of [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/).

`context_processors` is a list of dotted Python paths to callables that are used to populate the context when a template is rendered with a request. These callables take a request object as their argument and return a dict of items to be merged into the context. It defaults to an empty list.

```
# context_processors.py

def sample_context_processor(request):
    return {'key': 'value'}
```

---

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'myproject.context_processors.sample_context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```